# Tkinter button not defined

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
class Mybuttons():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frm= Frame(master)
        self.frm.grid()
        self.count= 0
        self.mybuttons()
        self.base=0
        self.exponent=0
        self.result=0
    def doonebase(self):
        self.base+=1
        self.btn1['text']= 'the base is ' + str(self.base)
    def dooneexponent(self):
        self.exponent+=1
        self.btn2['text']= 'the base is ' + str(self.exponent)
    def getresult(self):
        self.result= self.base * self.exponent
        self.btn3['text']= 'the answer is ' + str(self.result)
    def mybuttons(self):
        self.btn1=Button(self.frm)
        self.btn1['text']='base'
        self.btn1['command']=doonebase
        self.btn2=Button(self.frm)
        self.btn2['text']='exponent'
        self.btn2['command']=dooneexponent
        self.btn3=Button(self.frm)
        self.btn3['text']='result'
        self.btn3['command']=getresult
        self.btn1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.btn2.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.btn3.grid(row=1, column=1)

def try1():
        root= Tk()
        root.title('Compute an exponent!')
        root.geometry("200x300")
        threebuttons= Mybuttons(root)
        root.mainloop()
try1()
```

When I run this I get the error:

```
File "/home/goofy/Documents/lab10-1.py", line 23, in mybuttons
    self.btn1['command']=doonebase
NameError: name 'doonebase' is not defined
```

It does produce a window, but the buttons are not there.

When I comment out each of the lines that assign the 'command' to the functions, the code runs, and the buttons appear, but they don't do anything. I had tried defining each of the functions before the constructor and also tried after the `def mybuttons(self)`. I cannot seem to figure out why the code doesn't see the defined functions.

Comment: You need to do `self.doonebase`, not `doonebase`.  You'll need to do the same thing for `dooneexponent` and `getresult`.

Comment: @zondo Thank you so much! That totally fixed it. I am not sure how to give you credit for this answer because it is my first post but thank you!!!!

Comment: @zondo - can you write this as an answer - it might help someone else.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66: I was just typing one up.  It's done now.

Comment: @zondo - ty and a great answer, not only explained the fix - but why the original code didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define functions within a class, they are called "methods" and they are no longer in the global scope.  That means that you can't use `doonebase` or `doonexponent`.  They are now class attributes and should be accessed as such.  Since instance methods are given the instance as their first argument (`self`), you can use that to get the attributes.  Therefore, change `doonebase` to `self.doonebase`, `dooneexponent` to `self.dooneexponent`, and `getresult` to `self.getresult`